# viewing and controlling tv from laptop

Tags: smart-tv

hi all i was wondering if there was a way to remotly view and controll one of my smart tvs my problem is my little one shouts down every 10 mins for me to put something on her youtube neadless to say this is frustrating after a few times as its litrally after every video i would like to be able to open a window that allows me to controll  and view her tv from my laptop is this possible

so in short i wanna be able to open a window that shows me her tv screen and change a video on youtube without the need of having to go in there and changing it with the remote ??

Comment: You're going to have to clarify this a good deal more. What is the make and model of smart TVs, and what exactly are you trying to do with youtube - it's unclear.  Please [edit] to clarify what your probelm is more specifically.  Thanks!

Comment: its a sharp lc40f15012k basically i wanna be able to change what is on her tv from my laptop ideally i would like to open a window and change whats shes watching on her youtube as im litrally up and down all evening once a video that i have put on finishes shes shouting to have another put on